# Can't get the File Descriptor of a socket using Java

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, inputstream, file-descriptor

I'm new to Software Development and currently I am trying to get the file Descriptor of a socket, my job as an intern is to write a java Code (the new update) that has the same functions as a C Code (the older one). The C code is using a function called `getFd()` , after research I found that java has something similar to that which is `getFD()` or `getFileDescriptor()`. Somehow I cannot find them in the Socket Class

I've tried a bunch of solutions like using the `SocketImpl()` but it didn't work for me... I am stuck in this problem since 2 days and I have no idea what to do after trying dozens of Solutions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know the file descriptor? Did you know that Windows doesn't have file descriptors and Java code also runs on Windows?

Comment: @user253751 No I didn't know that...

Comment: what do you need the file descriptor for?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to attempt to translate C code line-for-line to Java. You must understand both languages and how things are done in each language.

Comment: @user253751 as I said there is a function in C that uses such a thing and I wanted to do the same thing with JAVA... I found out that I can use something else instead of the File Descriptor

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's bot that hard as I'm kind of familiar with the syntax of each langauage

Comment: but you are writing Java, not C. Are you going to call the C function even though you are writing Java? or are you going to call a Java function?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users you should probably try to use the Java API as intended by its designer.

That being said this is how you could access the file descriptor using reflection on Mac OSX and probably Linux too:

```
Method getImplMethod = ServerSocket.class.getDeclaredMethod("getImpl");
getImplMethod.setAccessible(true);
SocketImpl socketImpl = (SocketImpl) getImplMethod.invoke(serverSocket);

Field socketFdField = SocketImpl.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
socketFdField.setAccessible(true);
FileDescriptor fd = (FileDescriptor) socketFdField.get(socketImpl);

Field fileDescriptorFdField = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
fileDescriptorFdField.setAccessible(true);
int fdInt = fileDescriptorFdField.getInt(fd);
```